# Convert To Enum Option Not Found In Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, enums

I am using *EntityFramework 6* and *.NET Framework 4.5*.
I have created an enum in Model Browser and it appears in Enum Types. But when I right-click on the target field in my diagram, there is no such option as `Convert To Enum` option like [in here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj248772.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select the Property in the designer that you want to convert to an Enum and go to the Properties screen in Visual Studio (Press F4). In the VS Properties screen, there is a property named `Type`.

If you scroll all the way to the bottom of this `Type` dropdown list, the enum that you added to the model browser will be listed there. Select it, save changes and the model will regenerate the file for you. That property will now be of the Enum type.

Comment: thank you! would have been nice if they let the option remain in the context menu, but now i know thanks to you.

Comment: What is weird is the Convert to Enum option _should_ still be in the context menu... this is just a workaround. No clue why it isn't showing for you. I have the same exact version of everything you listed running and it shows for me.

Comment: For completeness: Convert to Enum option is only available when the type of the property is one of the types that can be the enum underlying type - Byte, SByte, Int16, Int32 or Int64. If the property type is not one of these types you cannot convert it to enum directly because the designer would not know what the underlying type should be and what's more important whether it would work with your database.